# Having trouble finding the domain of this function?

Tags: functions

The function that I'm trying to find the domain of is 
$$f(x) = 11.8x^{\frac{\log\left(\frac{39}{11.8}\right)}{\log(11)}}.$$
I know that this function can be evaluated for all non negative real numbers but I'm having trouble determining whether this function can take in negative numbers or not. I was wondering whether someone could explain if negative numbers can be inputted into this function and if they can't why not?

Comment: For non-integer $\alpha$, $x^{\alpha}$ becomes complex-valued  for negative $x$.

Comment: @NickS It does behave differently than $x^{2}$ if you input this function into a graphing calculator you find out it can't be evaluated at negative numbers whereas $x^{2}$ is defined everywhere

Comment: @KennethGoodenough what about if you have $x^{.4}$ it isn't complex valued for a negative x. You can plug that function into a graphing calculator and see that it has a real value for any real number.

Comment: oops, apologies, I misevaluated the power.

Comment: $x^r$ with $x<0$ and $r \in \mathbb R$, will be complex when x<0 and r is irrational.  And will be complex for certain rational $r$ as well.

Comment: @user262291, this only happens for non-integer powers, as in my first comment. One way to see this is that $z^{\alpha} = e^{\alpha\log(z)}$.

Comment: but .4 isn't an integer is a rational number right

Comment: Whoops, didn't see the dot before the $4$. What I forgot was that powers become multi-valued when working with complex numbers. For rational $\alpha = \frac{a}{b}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we get that $x^{\alpha} = e^{\alpha\log(x)} = e^{\frac{a}{b}\left(\textrm{Log}(|x|)+2\pi k i\right)}$, with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Note that for certain $k$, this will be real.

Answer (score 0):

A function where the exponent of $x$ is not a integer value is complex-valued for negative values of $x$.

Evaluating your exponent gives a value of approximately $0.4985$ so it will have non-real values for $x<0$.

Edit: Some non-integers may give real values but these cases are all rationals where as your value is irrational.